# Python: FileNotFound Error. No such file or directory

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, pandas

I'm writing a program in which Python is unable to read my file despite of me posting the absolute file path with Pandas. The weirdest part is that this program has worked before but it just doesn't now, and I can't get to the bottom of why. Here is the program and error:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Small_businesses1",encoding='latin1')
```

Error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Small_businesses1'
```

The file is for sure at that very location, I copy pasted the location! Any fixes will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you sure the file has no filename extension (e.g. `.csv`)? Windows likes hiding them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it seems that you have omitted the file type suffix try

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Small_businesses1.csv",encoding='latin1')
```

Comment: Oh wow I knew the solution would be something so simple and stupid! Thank you so much I'm going to go bang my head on a wall

Comment: Its very easily done, at least now you know to check for this when it happens again